# Get all terms from posts that have a certain post meta value

Tags: wordpress

I am trying to get all terms from a custom post type (artist) that have a meta_key(performance_date_1) and a meta_value(20220430) that I created with ACF.

This is what I have tried so far.

```
$events = get_terms( 'artist_event', array(
    'post_type' => 'artist',
    'taxonomy' => 'artist_event',
    'hide_empty' => false,
    'suppress_filters' => false,
    'meta_query' => array(
        // 'relation' => 'OR',
        array(
            'key' => 'performance_date_1',
            'compare' => '=',
            'value' => '20220430',
        )
    ),
) );
```

When using `get_terms` is the meta_query looking in taxonomy fields or post fields? I need the meta query to look for post fields to fix this issue I believe.

Comment: Check this: https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/query-posts-custom-fields/

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar situation. In my case, I resorted to using `array_filter` against posts via `WP_Query::have_posts` although this is certainly not the most performant solution.

```php
$events = array_filter(
    get_terms(array('taxonomy' => 'artist_event')), 
    function($term) {
        return (new WP_Query(array(
            'post_type' => 'artist',
            'posts_per_page' => -1,
            'tax_query' => array(
                'taxonomy' => 'artist_event', 
                'field' => 'slug', 
                'terms' => $term->slug,
            ),
            'meta_query' => array(
                array(
                    'key' => 'performance_date_1',
                    'compare' => '=',
                    'value' => '20220430',
                )
            ),
        )))->have_posts();
    }
);
```